# C++ Read a delimited file and create an object

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a file use the data line by line to create into an object.

The current file I have is like this and the code reading the file will be found below.

```
*   1223 Fake1 Name1  60  70  80  24 89  add1  Male
    1224 Fake2 Name2  61  70  81  80 24  add2  Male
    1225 Fake3 Name3  63  70  82  80 89  add3  Male
    1226 Fake4 Name4  63  70  83  80 88  add4  Male*
```

The problem I am having is that I need to put delimiters in the file so that a person can have more than one name and also the address can now hold multiple strings until the delimiter.

I would like to change my file to this;

```
   *1223 : Fa1 Name1 : 60 : 70 : 80 : 24 :89 : This will be address1 : Male 
    1224 : Fake2 Name2 : 61 : 70 : 81 : 80 :24 : This will be address2 : Male
    1225 : Fake3 Name3 : 63 : 70 : 82 : 80 :89 : This will be address3 : Male
    1226 : Fake4 Name4 : 63 : 70 : 83 : 80 :88 : This will be address4 : Male*
```

How can I update the code below so that it can use the delimiters to create an object?

```
void loadFile(Person people[], int* i)
{
    ifstream infile("people2.txt");

    if ( !infile.is_open()) {
      // The file could not be opened
        cout << "Error";
    }
    else
    {
        string str, str1, str2, str3, str4;
        int x[6];
        while(!infile.eof())
        {
            infile >> str1; 

            infile >> str2; 

            inile >> str; 
            x[0] = stoi(str);

            infile >> str; 
            x[1] = stoi(str);

            infile >> str; 
            x[2] = stoi(str);

            infile >> str; 
            x[3] = stoi(str);

            infile >> str; 
            x[4] = stoi(str);

            infile >> str; 
            x[5] = stoi(str);
            infile >> str3; 
            infile >> str4;             
            people[*i] = Person( x[0], str2 + " " + str1, x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], str3, str4);
            (*i)++;
        }
        infile.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Read one line at a time in a loop, split the line on the delimiter, and put the correct values in the correct fields. You can actually use the same [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) for both purposes.

Comment: `inile >> str;` this will never compile

Comment: Also, don't do `while (!infile.eof())`, it will not work as you expect it to because the `eofbit` flag will not be set until after you try to read from beyond the end of the file, meaning your loop will iterate once too many. Instead do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))` (or `while (infile >> ...)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use std::getline to read the file line by line, and also to split the string based on a specified delimiter. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>


int main() {
  std::ifstream infile("people2.txt");
  if (!infile) {
    std::cerr << "Could not open file." << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(infile, line)) {  // Read file line by line.
    std::string field;
    std::vector<std::string> separated_fields;
    std::istringstream iss_line(line);
    while (std::getline(iss_line, field, ':')) { // Split line on the ':' character
      separated_fields.push_back(field);    // Vector containing each field, i.e. name, address...
    }
    // Do something with the results
    separated_fields[0]; // ID
    separated_fields[1]; // Names
    separated_fields[2]; // Number
    separated_fields[3]; // Number
    separated_fields[4]; // Number
    separated_fields[5]; // Number
    separated_fields[6]; // Number
    separated_fields[7]; // Address
    separated_fields[6]; // Sex 
  }
}
```

You can then create your object in the section marked `// Do something with the results` either by passing the individual strings as you have in your example, or passing the vector to the constructor and dealing with each field there.